# How can I use formdata with axios post without 500 error code?

Tags: javascript, axios, multipartform-data, http-status-code-500, reactjs

```
import React ,{useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import {Container,Form,Row,Col,Figure,Table,Card,ListGroup, Spinner,Badge, Accordion,Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import ImageUpload from '../../shared/components/FormElements/ImageUpload'
import Input from '../../shared/components/FormElements/Input'
import {useForm} from '../../shared/hooks/form-hooks'
import {VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH,VALIDATOR_EMAIL, VALIDATOR_REQUIRE}  from '../../shared/util/validators'
import './NewRecipe.css'
import Ingredient from './Ingredient'
import Instruction  from './Instruction'
import {AuthContext} from '../../shared/context/auth-context'


 const NewRecipe = props => {
    const auth  = useContext(AuthContext)

    const [formState,inputHandler, setFormData]= useForm({
      title:{
        value:"",
        isValid:false
      },
      image:{
        value:null,
        isValid:false
      },
      readyInMinutes:{
        value:"",
        isValid:false
      },
      servings:{
        value:"",
        isValid:false
      },
      price:{
        value:"",
        isValid:false
      },
      ingredients:[{
        name:{
            value:"",
            isValid:false
          },
          amount:{
            value:"",
            isValid:false
          },
          measure:{
            value:"",
            isValid:false
          }
      }
      ],
      instructions:[
          {
            content:{
                value:"",
                isValid:false
              }
          }
      ]
     

    },false)
    const [ingredients,setIngredients] = useState([])
    const [ingredientCount,setIngredientCount] = useState(0)
    const [instructionCount, setInstructionCount] = useState(0)
    const [instructions, setInstructions] = useState([])

        
    const addIngredient = () => {
        setIngredientCount(ingredientCount=> ingredientCount + 1)
        setIngredients(prev => [...prev,ingredientCount])
    }
    const addInstruction = () => {
        setInstructionCount(instructionCount => instructionCount + 1)
        setInstructions(prev => [...prev, instructionCount])
    }
    const handleIngredientRemove = (index) => {
        setIngredients(ingredients.filter(ingredient => ingredient !== index))
        setIngredientCount(ingredientCount => ingredientCount - 1)   
    }
    const handleInstructionRemove = (index) => {
        setInstructions(ingredients.filter(ingredient => ingredient !== index))
        setInstructionCount(ingredientCount => ingredientCount - 1)  
    }
    const handleSubmit =  (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setFormData({...formState.inputs},false)
        

        try{
            console.log(formState.inputs)
            const formData = new FormData()
            const my_ingredients = new Array()
            const my_instructions = new Array()
        
            my_ingredients.push({name:formState.inputs.iName.value,amount:parseFloat(formState.inputs.amount.value),measure:formState.inputs.measure.value})
            console.log(my_ingredients)
           
            my_instructions.push({content:formState.inputs.content.value})
            
            formData.append('title',formState.inputs.title.value)
            formData.append('readyInMinutes',parseFloat(formState.inputs.readyInMinutes.value))
            formData.append('servings',parseFloat(formState.inputs.servings.value))
            formData.append('price',parseFloat(formState.inputs.price.value))
            formData.append('ingredients',JSON.stringify(my_ingredients))
            formData.append('instructions',JSON.stringify(my_instructions))
            formData.append('image',formState.inputs.image.value)
            console.log(formData.get('ingredients'))
            console.log(formData.get('instructions'))
            console.log(formData.get('image'))
            console.log(formData.get('price'))
            console.log(formData.get('servings'))
            console.log(formData.get('title'))
           
            const responseData =  axios.post(
                process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL+'/recipes/new',
                 formData,{
                 headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${auth.token}`} })
        
            console.log(responseData)
            console.log('2g')
            
           
          
        }
        catch(err){
           console.log(err.message)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='recipe-main'>
            <h3>-</h3>
            <Container className='new-recipe-container' >
                
                <Card  border="secondary" className='recipe-form'>
                    <Form className='form-container' >
                        <Input 
                            element='input'
                            type='text'
                            id='title'
                            name='title'
                            label='Title'
                            validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
                            errorText='Please enter a title...'
                            placeholder='Please enter a title...'
                            onInput={inputHandler} />
                        <Input 
                            element='input'
                            type='number'
                            id='readyInMinutes'
                            name='readyInMinutes'
                            label='ReadyInMinutes'
                            validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
                            errorText='Please enter a readyInMinutes...'
                            placeholder='Please enter a readyInMinutes...'
                            onInput={inputHandler} />    
                        <ImageUpload
                                id='image' 
                                name='image'
                                validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
                                errorText='Please import an image file.'
                                onInput={inputHandler}
                                
                        />
                        <Button className='increment-btn' variant="warning" size="lg" block onClick={addIngredient}>
                            Add Ingredient
                        </Button>
                        {ingredients.map(index => {
                            return ( <Ingredient  key={index} onInputHandler={inputHandler} deleteIngredientHandler={() => handleIngredientRemove(index)} iId={index} />)
                        }
                        )}
                       
                        <Input 
                            element='input'
                            type='number'
                            id='servings'
                            name='servings'
                            label='Servings'
                            validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
                            errorText='Please enter a servings...'
                            placeholder='Please enter a servings...'
                            onInput={inputHandler} />
                        <Input 
                            element='input'
                            type='number'
                            id='price'
                            name='price'
                            label='Price'
                            validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
                            errorText='Please enter a price...'
                            placeholder='Please enter a price...'
                            onInput={inputHandler} />
                        <Button className='increment-btn' variant="warning" size="lg" block onClick={addInstruction}>
                            Add Instruction
                        </Button>
                        {instructions.map(index => {
                            return   <Instruction key={index} iId={index} onInputHandler={inputHandler} deleteInstruction={() => handleInstructionRemove(index)} />
                        })}
                    <Button  type='submit' className='submit-btn' size="lg" block  onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Recipe</Button>
                    </Form>
                </Card>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
export default NewRecipe
```

I would like to ad my multipart/formdata with axios post and  authenticatiomn. I do not get any authentication error but i get 500 status code for server. Basically, I have my own api and want to post data to my own api. I am stuck in this. Thanks for your help from now. enter image description here

recipe model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator')


const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxLength: 280
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true, // this adds `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties
  toJSON: {
    // whenever the comment is converted to JSON
    transform(doc, json) {
      delete json.__v
      return json
    }
  }
})
const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  image:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  ingredients:[{
    name:{
      type:String,
      required:true
    },
    image:{
      type:String,
      required:true
    },
    amount:{
      type:Number,
      required:true
    },
    measure:{
      type:String,
      required:true
    }
  }],
  instructions:[{
    content:{
      type:String,
      required:true
    }
  }],
  readyInMinutes:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
  },
  servings:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
  },
  ratings:[{
    point:{
      type:Number,
      required:true
    }
  }],
  creator:{
    type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required:true,
    ref:'User'
  },
  comments:[commentSchema],
  nutrients:[{
    name:{
      type:String,
      required:true
    },
    amount:{
      type:Number,
      required:true
    }
  }],
  price:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
  }


})
recipeSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator)                                            //We plugin wiht mogooseValidator with our schema.
module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe',recipeSchema)                          //We called User model with recipeSchema
```

recipe cotroller.js

```
const HttpError = require('../models/HttpError')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt= require('jsonwebtoken')
const Recipe = require('../models/Recipe')
const User = require('../models/User')
const {validationResult} = require('express-validator')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uuid = require('uuid/v4')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const getAllRecipes = async (req, res, next) => {                               //We get all recipes to show users' recipes
   let recipes
   try{
     recipes = await Recipe.find({}).exec()
   }
   catch(err){
     const error = new HttpError('Something went wrong',500)
     return next(error)
   }
   if(!recipes){
     const error = new HttpError('Could not find any recipe',404)
     return next(error)
   }

   res.status(200).json({recipes:recipes.map(recipe => recipe.toObject({getters:true}))})
}
const getRecipesByUserId = async (req, res, next) => {                          // We want to get recipes by userId, so we can show user's recipes
   const userId = req.params.uid
   let existingUser
   try{
      existingUser = await User.findById(userId).populate('recipes')
   }
   catch(err){
     const error = new HttpError('Could not find any recipes provided user id',500)
     return next(error)
   }
   if(!existingUser){                                                           // We check if this user exist or not in our database.
     const error = new HttpError('Could not find any user provided user id',404)
     return next(error)
   }
   res.status(200).json({recipes:existingUser.recipes.map(recipe => recipe.toObject({getters:true}))})
}
const createRecipe = async (req, res, next) =>{                                 //We create a new recipe
  const errors = validationResult(req)
  if(!errors.isEmpty()){
    const error = new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data.',422)
    return next(error)
  }
  const {title,ingredients,instructions,readyInMinutes, servings, ratings,comments, nutrients,price} = req.body

  const createdRecipe = new Recipe({
    title,
    image:req.file.path,
    ingredients,
    instructions,
    readyInMinutes,
    servings,
    ratings:[],
    creator:req.userData.userId,
    comments:[],
    nutrients:[],
    price
  })
  let user
  try{
    user = await User.findById(req.userData.userId)                             // When we add a new recipe we need user's recipes array,too.That's why We need user who add this recipe.
  }
  catch(err){
    const errors = new HttpError('Something went wrong',500)
    return next(error)
  }
  if(!user){
    const error = new HttpError('This user does not exist',422)
    return next(error)
  }
  try{                                                                          // We need to do this.Because When we add a new recipe that affect user's recipes array, too.We want to make sure to add this recipe both collections.
      const sess = await mongoose.startSession()
      sess.startTransaction()
      await  createdRecipe.save({session:sess})
      user.recipes.push(createdRecipe)
      await user.save({session:sess})
      await sess.commitTransaction()
  }
  catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError('Created recipe failed, please create again',500)
    return next(error)
  }
  res.status(201).json({recipe:createdRecipe})
}
const updateRecipe = async (req, res, next) => {                             
  const errors = validationResult(req)
  if(!errors.isEmpty()){
    const error = new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data.',422)
    return next(error)
  }
  const recipeId  = req.params.rid
  let existingRecipe
  try
  {
    existingRecipe = await Recipe.findById(recipeId).populate('creator')
  }
  catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError('Something went wrong could not update place', 500)
    return next(error)
   }
   if(existingRecipe.creator.id !== req.userData.userId){                       // We want to know that creator and currentUser same person or not.
      const error = new HttpError('You are not allowed to update this recipe ',403)
      return next(error)
   }
    const {title,ingredients,instructions,readyInMinutes, servings, nutrients,price} = req.body
    existingRecipe.title = title
    existingRecipe.image = req.file.path
    existingRecipe.ingredients= ingredients
    existingRecipe.instructions = instructions
    existingRecipe.readyInMinutes = readyInMinutes
    existingRecipe.servings = servings
    existingRecipe.nutrients  = nutrients
    existingRecipe.price = price
    try{
      await existingRecipe.save()
    }
    catch(err){
      const error = new HttpError('Something went wrong could not update recipe', 500)
      return next(error)
     }
     res.status(200).json({recipe:existingRecipe.toObject({getters:true})})
}
const deleteRecipe = async (req, res, next) => {
  const recipeId = req.params.rid
  let recipe
  try{
    recipe = await Recipe.findById(recipeId).populate('creator')
  }
  catch(err){
    const error  = new HttpError('Something went wrong',500)
    return next(error)
  }
  if(!recipe){
    const error = new HttpError('This recipe does not exist',404)
    return next(error)
  }
  if(recipe.creator.id !== req.userData.userId){                                // We want to know that creator and currentUser same person or not.
    const error = new HttpError('You are not allowed to delete this recipe',403)
    return next(error)
  }
  const imagePath = recipe.image
  try{
    const sess = await mongoose.startSession()
    sess.startTransaction()
    await recipe.remove({session:sess})
    recipe.creator.recipes.pull(recipe)
    await recipe.creator.save({session:sess})
    await sess.commitTransaction()
  }
  catch(err){
    const error  = new HttpError('Something went me wrong',500)
   return next(error)
  }
  fs.unlink(imagePath, err => {
    console.log(err);
  })

     res.status(200).json({message:'Deleted recipe'})
}


exports.getAllRecipes = getAllRecipes
exports.getRecipesByUserId = getRecipesByUserId
exports.createRecipe = createRecipe
exports.updateRecipe = updateRecipe
exports.deleteRecipe = deleteRecipe
```

[image]
[image]

Here's my dev tools newtwork tab with my request headers

Answer (score 1):

error 500 (Internal server error) is something related to your server not React. so try to find the issue in your server.

Comment: Basically, I found my error in my server. I try to send array objects with formdata and get Cast Error and Validation Error for array of objects.
How can I send my array of objects with formdata?

Comment: have your problem fixed